# Which domain should have 'abuse' or 'postmaster' or "fbl" email accounts?

Tags: smtp, abuse, email

Consider that I am providing SMTP services for several clients and the sender / SMTP domain is mails.mysmtp.com. When client A is using my email infrastructure, he may use from address (from header) as 'info@client1domain.com', same way client B may use an account 'info@client2domain.com'.

My question here is - which domain should have the 'postmaster' or 'abuse' or 'fbl' accounts? My domain or client domain?

Comment: Postmaster and abuse are [well defined](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2142). But what is fbl supposed to be?

Comment: It is "feedback loop"

Answer (score 2):

Both.  You will have them for mysmtp.com and they will have them for their own domains.

People who look at the headers will see your mail server, and possible email you if the client's postmaster@ address doesn't lead to satisfaction.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But in idle scenario, it is difficult for service provider (in this example its me) to check the inbox of client accounts. If we have control over client's accounts we can take necessary action. When ISP sends a complaint, will they send it to both accounts by default?

Comment: No, you certainly can't check their email.  That's the problem with letting them use a domain you don't control. Some will send it to the domain's admin, some to the actual mail server's admin.

Comment: If you are actually hosting the email for these domains (client1domain.com's MX record points to a server you control) then you can do what you want with postmaster@.  But if you don't control the domain, and just let people use it as an reply to address, you can't.

Comment: @mark http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/ISP%20Spam%20Issues is a good place to start looking for more info.

Answer (score 1):

To use FBL with your IPs you need to set the `ENVELOPE FROM` address to your own domain, even if your clients use their own domain in From and Reply-To headers. That makes it necessary to set the FBL email address to your own domain, alongwith abuse@ and postmaster@ addresses. Your clients should have their own abuse@ and postmaster@ address at their own domain, and you don't necessarily need access to those inboxes. Most spam reporters will send the abuse report to `ENVELOPE FROM` address hosting domain, which is you.